# Allow only rdesktop client on Raspberry Pi

Tags: users, raspberry-pi, account-restrictions, restricted-shell

I have an internet connected windows PC thats part of a domain with full controls and restrictions. I have been asked to provide internet connection to another room.

There are quite a few restrictions on my choice of hardware and software.

My plan, after many modifications, is to use a Rpi3 with rdesktop to remotely log into an internet-enabled Windows PC. Performance is not an issue.

But I am concerned that curious user would definitely start tinkering with the RPi.

**TLDR;**
Is there any way I can restrict the RPi user to only be able to use rdesktop (or equivalent rdp/vnc) client? Something like internet cafes at airports where you can only use a web browser and all the fancy commands and key combos are disabled?

Regards.

Comment: What OS are you planning to use for the Rpi3? Maybe a ThinClientOS would be a good place to start, lile http://winterminal.com (i don‘t know winterminal, this is just an example and a place to start).

Comment: I was thinking Rasbian? The choice of OS is flexible. I will look into thinclient OSes.

Comment: The clean way is to use some kind of hardware (the existing windows PC, the RaspPi next to the Windows PC, whatever), with no physical access to the third party, to offer internet connection on a LAN port (or a WLAN access point) which is directly "tunnelled" to the ISP router without becoming part of the local LAN segment your windows PC is on. E.g. with a VLAN setup on the ISP router, or with a firewall and NAT on the RaspPi, etc. Then the people in the other room can connect whatever devices they want to the LAN/WLAN AP, and everything is safe.